# ERROR : use plugin pdf_viewer + firebase_messaging

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use advance_pdf_viewer 2.0.0 and firebase_messaging 10.0.0 in one app.
an error appears when i display a pdf file

```
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4269 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
```

[Error flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNmTN.png)

any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

This won't fully answer the question, but it might help.

It is not all of FirebaseMessaging, just appears to be FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage.

If you don't need onBackgroundMessage, comment it out to see if this fixes it.